# java display grid of cells to output from method

Tags: java

here is the code I am working on I updated it,  got some code from online maybe stackflow and edited it like the parse part i dont understand everything about that code but enough to get it to work and most of what is going on and Thread.Sleep but i can figure that out though basically,  I am lost on some things...for example the user input which has user input values for populated cells (i,j),    and in displayGrid the program will calculate and display either a " " (space) or a "#",  i got that part okay except it prints one line down on the 10x10 grid further than it should,  for example if it prints out on line 7 horizontally,  it should actually be on line 6 horizontally.  Also I have to now use updateGrid method to update the grid.  For example if cell is populated i have to find out the neighbor cells.  each cell has up to 8 neighbors.  First how to I figure out how to calculate the neighbors?  Can anyone give me some hints please...Bijan

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Name {

    public static String name; 
}

public class Project8a {

    private static int populatedCells = 1;
    private static int unpopulatedCells = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ParseException{


        //int populatedCells = 100, unpopulatedCells = 100;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int mat[][] = new int[10][10];

        //get time of day, etc...
        timeOfDay();

        System.out.println("\nPlease enter list of (i,j) pairs for populated cells (negative i or j to quit) : ");

        int i = scan.nextInt();
        int j = scan.nextInt();

        while(i >= 0 && j >= 0){

            mat[i][j] = 1;
            i = scan.nextInt();
            j = scan.nextInt();

        }


        System.out.println("Enter number of time steps : ");
        int numberOfTimeSteps = scan.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Intial Grid : \n");

        /************************************

        attempt to loop through time steps
        and try to use / test 'sleep' method
        do {
        displayGrid(mat);
        }while(mat[i][j] <= 10); 

        *************************************/
        //display and print-out 10x10 grid
        displayGrid(mat);
        //update cells within 10x10 grid 
        updateGrid(mat);

    }

        public static void displayGrid(int mat[][]){


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                System.out.print(i);
            }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("          ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                System.out.println(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){

                if(mat[i][j] == 1)
                    System.out.print("#");
                else  {
                    System.out.print(" ");

                }
            }

            /***************************

            attempt to make outer-edge
            cells = '0' 
            if(i == 0 || j == 0){
                mat[i][j] = 0;
            }

            ****************************/




        }


            } 


    public static void updateGrid(int mat[][]) 

            throws InterruptedException{
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int newArray[][] = new int[mat[i].length][mat[j].length];
            int populatedCells = 1;
            //for(b = 0; b < [mat[i].length][mat[j].length];
            //int unpopulatedCells = 2;
            int neighborCells = 8;

            if(neighborCells <= 1 || neighborCells >= 4)
                populatedCells = 0;
            else if (neighborCells == 3)
                populatedCells = 1;

            /************************************************************************************** 

                    For a cell that is “populated”, if the cell has <= 1 neighbors, 
                    or >= 4 neighbors, it  dies (becomes 0). Otherwise, 
                    it survives (remains 1).   For a cell that is not populated, 
                    if the cell has exactly 3 neighbors, it becomes  populated (becomes 1). 
                    Cells on the edge always remain unpopulated (0).

            **************************************************************************************/

            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.print("Now testing sleep method (for 5 seconds) : ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("5");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("4");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("3");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("2");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("1");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print("0");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print(".");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print(".");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print(".\n");
            Thread.sleep(2500);
            System.out.print("\nBlast!!! It worked!!!\n\n");
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            System.out.println("Ah you thought it was over HAHA!!!");
            System.out.println("Actually that was six seconds!!!\n");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print("S");
            Thread.sleep(750);
            System.out.print("E");
            Thread.sleep(750);
            System.out.print("E" + " ");
            Thread.sleep(750);
            System.out.print("Y");
            Thread.sleep(750);
            System.out.print("A");
            Thread.sleep(750);
            System.out.print("H");
            Thread.sleep(750);
            System.out.print("!");
            Thread.sleep(750);
            System.out.print("!");
            Thread.sleep(750);
            System.out.print("!" + " ");
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            for (int c = 0; c < Name.name.length(); c++) {
                System.out.print(Name.name.charAt(c));
                Thread.sleep(750L); 
            }



        }public static int timeOfDay() throws ParseException{

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("First off,  please enter your name for the database storage : ");
            Name.name = scan.nextLine();

            Date date = new Date() ;
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm") ;
            dateFormat.format(date);
            //System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

            if(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)).after(dateFormat.parse("6:00"))&& dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)).before(dateFormat.parse("11:59")))
            {
                System.out.println("\nOkay " + Name.name + ", hope you're having a good morning - lets play!!!");
            }
            else if(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)).after(dateFormat.parse("11:59"))&& dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)).before(dateFormat.parse("17:00")))
            {
                System.out.println("\nOkay " + Name.name + ", hope you're having a good afternoon - lets play!!!");
            }
            else if(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)).after(dateFormat.parse("17:00"))&& dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)).before(dateFormat.parse("18:59")))
            {
                System.out.println("\nOkay " + Name.name + ", hope you're having a good evening - lets play!!!");
            }
            else if(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)).after(dateFormat.parse("18:59"))&& dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)).before(dateFormat.parse("23:59")))
            {
                System.out.println("\nOkay " + Name.name + ", hope you're having a good night so far - lets play!!!");
            }
            return populatedCells;


        }

}
```

Comment: This thing is as easy as updating a 2D array cell and just print it out. What is stopping you?

Answer (score 0):

It may be clearer to use a list rather than a 2D array, so simplifying a little:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project8a {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Please enter list of (i,j) pairs for populated cells (negative i or j to quit) : ");

        List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (true) {
                int one =  scan.nextInt();
                if (one < 0) break;

                int two =  scan.nextInt();
                if (two < 0) break;            

                cells.add(new Cell(one, two)); 
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Intial Grid : ");
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            System.out.println(cell);
        }
    }

    static class Cell {
        private int one, two;
        Cell(int one, int two) { this.one = one; this.two = two; }
        public void setOne(int one) { this.one = one; }
        public void setTwo(int two) { this.two = two; }
        public int getOne() { return one; }
        public int getTwo() { return two; }

        public String toString() {
            return "[ " + one + ", " + two + " ]";          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: richard the project and the teacher ask to use multi-d arrays for this project...and quite a bit of stuff you are using to do your code I havent even learned yet...and i dont want to code to break...the later code will keep updating the cells and change their locations...but thanks for trying to help me,  Bijan